# AngularJS, Object is displayed in unwanted places

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[**First a link to my code.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pb1ReYCYKM8ep7xyv60T)

I have the following code:

```
<div>
<form ng-show="hiddenAdd">
    ID: <input type="text" ng-model="website.id" /> <br />
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="website.name" /> <br />
    Secret Key:<input type="text" ng-model="website.secretKey" /> <br />
    Public Key:<input type="text" ng-model="website.publicKey" /> <br />
    User Idetification: <input type="text" ng-model="website.userIdentification" /> <br />
    <button>save</button>
    <button>cancel</button>
</form>
</div>
<!--Holdes the website form details-->

<!--Holdes the website form -->
<div ng-show='hiddenDetail'>
    <p>Details</p>
    id: {{website.id}}<br />
    name: {{website.name}}<br />
</div>
```

This page has a `form` that can add new website with info and a detail section that
displays details about the website from the list, like that:

[image]

The problem starts when I press details button I get site details inside 
the form, like that:
[image]

I understand why this happens but how do I isolates the object?
I know it has something with `scope` isolation but I'm not sure as to how implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the same `website` variable to display and add new element. You need to bind your form to a different object and the rest would work.  Also you need to create new model each time you click `Add Website` button.

See this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WZEjviUjPW7jVBRBehcx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-hide=""` for all elements you don't want to show.

Comment: you can use it to hide certain elements. If you put in the form tag /or wherever you like/ you can define what to hide. Here is the description: 
 http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide